# Embedding SoundCloud - Can we do it? How to do it? Do we want it?

Tags: feature-request

I noticed on a few other SE sites (e.g., Video Production and Music Practice and Theory) that they can include a link to a publicly available SoundCloud track (and YouTube, potentially), and it will be rendered with an embedded player. Given the nature of our SE, this would be a very relevant tool.

Assuming that it was a universal feature, I tried to do it for the Bioacoustics Beta site, but it still shows as a url/link. Does anyone know how we can do this? Do we need to request this feature from someone at SE?

Comment: I added "do we want it" to the title of this question to hopefully encourage other users to see this question and interact with it to show interest in adding this feature!

Answer (score 7):

I was hoping one of the SE moderators would provide an explanation, but from what I can see:

- If a site allows code snippet it can be done, see 2nd answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103850/allow-sound-file-uploads-in-questions-and-answers).
- I think we can put in a request on meta.stackexchange.com as they did [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72365/can-an-embedded-audio-player-be-added-to-audio-se-and-music-se) for Audio.SE and Music.SE?

It may be that we first need to graduate to a public beta before this will be considered (fair enough), but if it is possible (and it is), then it would be incredibly valuable for our site.

**I hope some moderators can provide input?**

Comment: For something specific to a particular site like this issue, a request on this Meta site would actually be more appropriate. (This question is already sufficient for that.) If there's consensus from the community that this should be enabled for the site (and it's a request that is something we can do), then the site mods can escalate it to CMs/staff by adding the [status-review] tag to the Meta post... Or that's what I would recommend on a site that has mods, anyway. Since this site's in private beta and doesn't yet have mods, we'd probably suggest waiting until pro-tem mods are elected.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance! We will revisit this at Public Beta.